# Why use \' escape sequence instead of just '?

Tags: python

Is there any difference between:

```
print "I am John Doe\'s cousin."
```

and:

```
print "I am John Doe's cousin."
```

Comment: The second form is more readable.

Comment: The escape sequence is only required if you are enclosing your string within single quotation marks eg `'I am John Doe\'s cousin.'`

Comment: There is no difference in your example. Where did you see it?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the line with out the \' and if you wrote it using single quotation marks(an apostrophe) python would read the line as

```
print ('I am doe')
```

then would give an error because python doesn't expect anything after the apostrophe

when you use a backslash python takes the apostrophe as a string and not an end of string

when you use the regular quotation mark it doesn't matter, python will read it the same